# what should be updated to handle log4j vulnerability in android?

Tags: android, log4j

Since log4j vulnerability is found in java, I am concerned of what actions I need to take in android side.
[Apache Log4j Vulnerability](https://security.googleblog.com/2021/12/apache-log4j-vulnerability.html) from google security blog says **Android is not aware of any impact to the Android Platform or Enterprise.**

Does this mean I as an Android Developer don't really need to take any actions to avoid log4j vulnerability? Or I still need to find (either directly or transitive) log4j dependency in my project then disable/remove specific dependency(in this case log4j) using [this type of code](https://tomgregory.com/how-to-exclude-gradle-dependencies/) if it appears to be in my project?

is there anything else(maybe like android studio version, Gradle version, or Kotlin version etc?) I need to take action on log4j velnerability in android side?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Log4shell vulnerability needs log4j AND JNDI to exist. See my answer to: [Does the Log4j vulnerability affect Android users?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/243232/3573)

Comment: @MorrisonChang I found [this video](https://youtu.be/uyq8yxWO1ls?t=900) saying that we need to disable specific log4j dependency. do you think this is one of the necessary fix to apply to android project?

Comment: Do you have log4j in your Android application? If so why and what part of your Android application depends upon it.

Comment: My project does not directly depending on log4j dependency, however I would like to prevent the old problematic version of log4j from being used as transitive dependency in my project in the future as well.